# JSON to PHP: Obtaining the Object Array data within an Object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

I have two JavaScript classes:

```
function Sensor(sensorNumber, name, m, b, selected) {
    "use strict";
    this.sensorNumber = sensorNumber;
    this.name = name;
    this.m = m;
    this.b = b;
    this.selected = selected;
}
```

The Chart class below contains an Array of the Sensor class above, some variables, and a timeSpan class:

```
function Chart(index, allsensors) {
    "use strict";
    this.chartName = $("#newChartName").val();
    this.chartNumber = index;
    this.sensorsArray = allsensors;
    this.time = new TimeSpan();
}
```

I send the "chart" object variable to PHP via Jquery AJAX:

```
function obtainChartData(chart) {
    "use strict";
    $.ajax({
        url: 'server/ExtractTelemetry.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(chart),
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
}
```

PHP Receives it, and this is where I'm stuck. I need to obtain the "this.Selected" for each element in the sensor object array.

```
<?php
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $chart = json_decode($json);
    echo $startTime = $chart->time->startSec." "; //CORRECT
    echo $endTime = $chart->time->endSec." "; //CORRECT
    echo $chartName = $chart->chartName." "; //CORRECT
    echo $chartNumber = $chart->chartNumber." "; //CORRECT

    for(...) {
    echo $allSensors = $chart->allSensors[someIndexValue]->selected; //why does this not work??
    }
?>
```

UPDATE:

Here is the PHP Error output

[image]

JSON output(shortened but should be enough info):

```
object(stdClass)#1 (4) {  
["chartName"]=>  string(7) "Chart#1"  
["chartNumber"]=>  int(1)
["sensorsArray"]=>  object(stdClass)#2 (44) {    
    ["B0"]=>    object(stdClass)#3 (5) {      
        ["sensorNumber"]=>      int(0)      
        ["name"]=>      string(10) "SRBUS(mV)"      
        ["m"]=>      string(6) "1.2811"      
        ["b"]=>      string(8) "-4.1559"      
        ["selected"]=>      bool(false)    
        }    
    ["B1"]=>    object(stdClass)#4 (5) {
        ["sensorNumber"]=>      int(1)      
        ["name"]=>      string(10) "SRBUS(mA)"      
        ["m"]=>      string(6) "0.6137"      
        ["b"]=>...
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `$chart->sensorsArray[someIndexValue]->selected`?

Comment: @Phylogenesis, you are correct... I fixed it, but that leads to another error. I updated the image

Comment: You'll have a lot more luck using `var_dump($chart);` and looking at its actual structure.

Comment: Show please the `json` string passed to the server.

Comment: I added it to my post

Comment: Then you need to reference as follows: `$chart->sensorsArray->B0->selected` or [pass `true` as the second parameter of `json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) in order to return associative arrays rather than objects.

Comment: **"$chart->sensorsArray->B0->selected"** works =) passing true in json decode gives the following error however: "trying to get property of non-object..." I'm guessing this has to do with the other parameters like the int or string one?

Comment: @gfds12345 Yes, passing `true` means that you would reference it as `$chart['sensorsArray']['B0']['selected']`. It would just make iterating over the `sensorsArray` easier, as you could use something like `foreach ($chart['sensorsArray'] as $sensorKey => $sensorValue) { ... }`.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the clarification. I need to wrap my head around this and do some more reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

json_decode returns an stdObject. Properties of that object can be access by

`$myObject = json_decode($myString);`

`$myObject->myProperty;`

If you want an array returned from json_decode pass a secnond parameter 'true'

```
$myArray = json_decode($myString, true);
```

Comment: That leads to this error: **<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\CSUNSat1-TelemetryWebApp\CSUNSat1Telemetry\server\ExtractTelemetry.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br /><br /><b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object**

Comment: the chart itself is an array then also: this should work: $startTime = $chart['time']['startSec'];